# Debugging functional tests with phpunit just hang unless I toggle "stop/start listenting for php debug connections"

Tags: testing

Trying to get tests up and running by following https://www.previousnext.com.au/blog/running-and-debugging-phpunit-tests-phpstorm-ddev-and-xdebug. Seems to work, except having an issue with functional tests. If I disable xdebug, the test runs in like 5 secs. If I enable xdebug and try to "debug the test", it just hangs forever.

If I wait like 30s then toggle "stop/start listening for PHP Debug Connections" in phpstorm, a second "standard input code" tab opens in the debug panel and it continues to hang. Clicking "resume program" continues the execution, but a few seconds later I need to do it again. This happens a few times and the test eventually completes, but something about xdebug seems to be causing things to get stuck.

I'm reproducing with breakpoints in NodeAdminTest::testContentAdminSort and UiHelperTrait::drupalLogin.

Answer (score 0):

Increasing the "max simultaneous connections" to 3+ in the phpstorm settings fixes the problem.